# Using shared_ptr to end multithreaded loops on interrupt

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to gracefully shut down several threads in loops when I interrupt a program (with SIGINT). Right now I use a callback that changes the state of a shared_ptr (which was copied to each thread) to indicate to all the other threads that it's time to break the loop (the threads check the state of the shared_ptr each iteration). This works, but I was wondering if it was "good" programming practice?

Comment: Your approach is reasonable, but you will want to make sure that the new value of the flag is appropriately read by the different threads. `std::atomic` is useful for this if you have access to C++11.

Comment: Define "changes the state of a shared_ptr".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed to be safe to modify a shared pointer in a signal handler. Nor is modification of a shared pointer safe (except copying which is safe despite modifying the internal state) across multiple threads

What would be safe is to use `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` as a flag and modify it in the signal handler. However, `sig_atomic_t` does not guarantee synchronisation to other threads than the one that handles the signal.

If you can rely on `std::atomic<bool>` being lock free (which isn't guaranteed by the standard), it would also be valid for modification in a signal handler, as well as guaranteeing thread synchronisation.

Otherwise, you could use a thread local `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` for the signal handler, and once change is detected in one thread, broadcast the information to other threads using a secondary thread syncronisation method (atomic, condition variable, etc.).

Another approach: you could have one thread simply waiting for the signal (no need for a sig-atomic flag), and once received, proceed with the thread synchronised broadcasting (same second phase as in previous suggestion). Note that the signal would have to be masked for other threads so that it is given for the waiting thread to handle. However, there is no good API for waiting for a signal in standard C++. There is `sigwait` in the POSIX standard, if you can rely on that.